# How do I query categories from different custom post types in a WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom hook to show custom post types in a select field on a form. I am trying to pull specific categories from those custom post types only. Currently I have it working but it pulls all the posts from the selected custom post types into the select field. When I add any Category Parameters or Tag Parameters it stops working.

Here is my code:

```
add_filter('frm_setup_new_fields_vars', 'add_rental_field_function', 3, 21);
add_filter('frm_setup_edit_fields_vars', 'add_rental_field_function', 3, 21);

function add_rental_field_function($values, $field){

    if($field->id == 21){
        $arrayPositions = array();
        $pushobj = array(
            'value' => ""
        );
        array_push($arrayPositions, $pushobj);
        $positionQuery = new WP_Query( array(  
            'post_type' =>  array ('available_rentals', 'farrell_storage', 'farrell_commercial'), 
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'orderby' => "menu_order", 
            'order' => "ASC",
        
        ) );
        if ( $positionQuery->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $positionQuery->have_posts() ) {
                $positionQuery->the_post();
                
                $title=get_the_title();
                
                $pushobj = array(
                    'value' => get_the_title(),
                    'label' => $label
                );
                array_push($arrayPositions, $pushobj);
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }

        $values['options'] = $arrayPositions;
    }
    return $values;
}
```

Comment: provide the code in which you get the issue.

Comment: When I add any of the below category parameters it stops working:

cat (int) 
category_name (string)
category__and (array) 
category__in (array) 
category__not_in (array)

Comment: I am not sure what kind of setup you have but You need to make sure you've connected `category` taxonomy to all the CPTs that you're using in the query since you're using multiple post type in your query.